# Cannot set ProviderService in configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am trying to move my app.config ef settings to code.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
                       type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
                 invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
                 type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Currently all I was able to set is the `defaultConnectionFactory`:

```
public class SqlServerCompactConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SqlServerCompactConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"));
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory());

        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", new System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices());
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", new System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices());
    }
}
```

For the last 2 lines I am getting the following error:

> 'SqlCeProviderServices' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'

I got no idea what to add here... Intellisense is showing nothing an so is the class when I use `GoToDefinition` there is no constructor...

Comment: Check for singleton - something like static `Instance` property.

Comment: that's just it ! If you wanna post that as a answer - I will accpet it ! Thanks alot for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually such service classes are implemented as singletons.

For instance, `SqlProviderServices` class contains the following:

```
//
// Summary:
//     The Singleton instance of the SqlProviderServices type.
public static SqlProviderServices Instance { get; }
```

I can't check now, but I'm pretty sure `SqlProviderService` class has something similar.